# Django : When is sessionid cookie set ? [ Is it available by default ? ]

Tags: python, database, django, session, session-cookies

I am trying to track the user - without login. For that I tried using `sessionid` or django sessions.

**View:**

```
# Associating data with sessionid
ob = MyModel(session_key=request.session.session_key, data='abc')
ob.save()
```

Intention was to save specific data for each browser session.

**Raises Error:**

```
# session_key not found
```

I checked the cookies on the browser, there is only `csrftoken`.
`sessionid` was not in the cookie list.

I assumed that the `sessionid` is maintained no matter what ? But seems like that is not the case.

So, When is `sessionid` created ? How can I manage `session` without user login ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default behavior is to only populate the session if you access or modify a key in the `session` dict-like object.

To avoid this behavior set [`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-save-every-request) to `True` in your `settings.py` file. This makes sure that a session is saved on each request, even if you didn't modify the session object.

The authentication middleware has no bearing on sessions; by default django supports anonymous sessions.